# How to explode a string in php?

Tags: php, explode

I have a string like this-

```
Course_13_Laravel_Batch_15_Day_22
```

and I want to get this output

```
C-13-L-B-15-D-22
```

How can I do this?
Here is my code-

```
<?php
$string = "Course_13_Laravel_Batch_15_Day_22";
$dim = explode(" ", $string);
$str = "";
foreach($dim as $item){
    if(is_numeric( $item)){
        $str = $str."-".substr($item, 0, 2);
    }else{

        $str = $str."-".substr($item, 0, 1);
    }
}
$str = substr($str,1);
echo $str;
?>
```

Comment: Why are you exploding by a " " space when you have _?

Comment: Voting to close due to typographical error. Literally replace the space `" "` with a `"_"` and it all works as expected: https://3v4l.org/CWbqC. **Edit** - why the dowvotes? OP has a clear input, expected output and one of the best MCVEs I've seen in a while. Just vote for close due to typo, there's nothing wrong with the question.

Comment: @mario So provide a constructive answer with a working regex instead of bashing OP for choosing a different solution.

Comment: Because I want to replace  the _ with a - and first character of every word.

Comment: (@Look I feel it's a waste of time to answer a question titled undescriptively with "explode a string". Much less after closevoting anyway. And: `preg_replace("/([A-Z]|\d+)[a-z]*_/", "$1-", $s);`)

Answer (score 3):

I was just working on the regexp as the comments came in...

```
$string = "Course_13_Laravel_Batch_15_Day_22";
echo preg_replace(array('/([a-zA-Z]).*?_/', '/([0-9]+)_/'), '$1-', $string);
```

Output:

```
C-13-L-B-15-D-22
```

Comment: Its a TYPO guys, we normally make a comment, ___like already made above___ and just close these questions. They are almost never any use to others!

Comment: @RiggsFolly Agreed, but I think this answer proposes a far better way to solve OPs problem than the explode/foreach method that he was using and so it is potentially useful to others.

Comment: more simple, clever and easy to understand: preg_replace(array("/[a-z]/", "/_/"), array('','-'), $string);

Comment: @vasilenicusor probably, but makes assumptions about the format of OPs data that may not be true. e.g. what if it's `course_15_hello` (i.e. all lowercase) or `course8_5_mixed` (mixed alphanumeric)? I've tried to be as general as possible.

Answer (score 0):

```
$string='Course_13_Laravel_Batch_15_Day_22';

$data=explode('_',$string); // since there is underscore to differ every work/number i use it as my delimiter

foreach($data as $row){
    if(is_numeric($row)){ //check if my array field value is a number
    $newArray[] = $row;
}
else{
        $newArray[]=  $row[0]; //You can access  single characters in a string by using "square brackets"
    }
}


$data=implode('-',$newArray); // merge array fields to a string using implode function and dash delimiter 
  echo $data;
```

And the output is :

*C-13-L-B-15-D-22*

You can access  single characters in a string
by using "square brackets"

Comment: Could you please also explain me why the downvote?

Comment: Its a TYPO guys, we normally make a comment, ___like already made above___ and just close these questions. They are almost never any use to others! (not my DV)

Comment: It's too little explanation on your code changes really. (Also handling every other string task with `explode` is poor advise to newcomers.)

Comment: Thank you will put some more explanation to my code to improve my answer.